# A simple plot returns empty, even though specific points values exist

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I'm in a bit of a pickle:

I try to plot a graph of a simple function, and for some reason unknown to me, it is drawn blank even though evaluation of the function at specific points returns the required values. My code is as follows:

```
A = 0.1;
B = 0.11;
CParam[x_] :=  BesselK[2, A/x] BesselI[0, B/x] + BesselI[2, A/x] BesselK[0, B/x];
Plot[Log[Log[-CParam'[x]]], {x, 10^-8, 10^-5}]
```

However, typing `{Log[Log[-CParam'[10^-5]]], Log[Log[-CParam'[10^-6]]], 
 Log[Log[-CParam'[10^-7]]], Log[Log[-CParam'[10^-8]]]}` returns `{6.91618835667271168, 9.211416996515317434, 11.5130562034263446895, 
13.81552593513862411174}`.

Why doesn't `Plot` work properly?

Thanks

Comment: try `LogLinearPlot`, and try manually specifying `PlotRange`

Comment: you also may need to do `Plot[Evaluate[expression],..]` because of the derivative

Comment: Nope. Neither work.

Comment: Seems to be a bug.  Try `ListLinePlot@ Table[Log[Log[-CParam'[x]]], {x, Subdivide[10^-8, 10^-5, 100]}]` (I'm on V11.0.0.)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2. That did it - I think I would use that in other places as well.

Comment: I'd suggest you post that as an answer.

Comment: Works fine under `"10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug in `Plot[]`.

Aside from making a table and `ListPlot`-ing it, such as in my comment,

```
ListLinePlot@ Table[Log[Log[-CParam'[x]]], {x, Subdivide[10^-8, 10^-5, 100]}]
```

one could use `NDSolve` to get adaptive sampling:

```
ListLinePlot@
 NDSolveValue[{y[x] == Log[Log[-CParam'[x]]], z'[x] == 1, 
   z[10^-8] == 0}, y, {x, 10^-8, 10^-5}, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Adaptive sampling is not needed here, but in an oscillatory function, it could be helpful, should `Plot[]` fail as in this case.

```
Options[adaptiveListLinePlot] = Options[ListLinePlot];
adaptiveListLinePlot[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{y, z, a1, b1},
   {a1, b1} =              (* open sampling *)
    Rescale[{Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon, 1 - Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon}, {0, 1}, {a, b}]; 
   ListLinePlot[
    NDSolveValue[{y[x] == f, z'[x] == 1, z[a1] == 0}, y, {x, a1, b1}, PrecisionGoal -> 3],
    opts]
   ];

adaptiveListLinePlot[Sin[x^2], {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I can verify the comment of @Michael E2 as I ran into the same problem with LogPlot on Version 11.0.
The solution he suggested worked for me by extracting the calculation from inside `Plot` into `Table`.
So for your problem it works like this:

```
A = 0.1;
B = 0.11;
CParam[x_] := BesselK[2, A/x] BesselI[0, B/x] + BesselI[2, A/x] BesselK[0, B/x];
stepIncrement = 10^(-8);
data = Table[Log[Log[-CParam'[x]]], {x, 10^-8, 10^-5, stepIncrement}];
ListPlot[data]
```

Choose the value of `stepIncrement` to a value that fulfills your requirements regarding precision.