# how to style multi-value interpolation function plot?

Tags: plotting, interpolation

Is there a cleaner way to apply different styles to the different channels of a multi value interpolation function?

here is a 2-output interpolation function:

```
f = Interpolation[Table[ {x, N@{Sin[x], Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}]]
```

if we just plot it the two functions take the same style

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Here is one way to separately style:

```
Plot[{f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

This feels inefficient, apparently this computes both interpolations twice.
I also cant figure an incantation to do this without explicitly listing..

```
Plot[Table[f[x][[i]], {i, 2}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

doesn't work.

We can crunch out a table and use `ListPlot`, but that seems unsatisfactory.

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I vaguely remember similar question where the answer was that `Plot` sees `f[x]` as a single object and therefore only recognizes one `PlotStyle` whereas `Plot` sees `{f[x][[1]],f[x][[2]]}` as two objects (as you've discovered).  I wish I could remember but it wasn't that long ago and it had a good explanation of the issue.

Comment: just found this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8637/2079 -- havent gone through to see if anything there works.

Comment: Mr.Wizard's [`styleSplitter`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87113/22013) works as it stands.

Comment: I can report this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87113/2079 works.  I dont think this is quite a duplicate since I hold out hope there is a cleaner method specific the the multi-value interpolation function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the sampling is dense enough, as it usually is in `NDSolve` output, `ListLinePlot` will do style each curve separately.

```
ListLinePlot[f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[f, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: nice.. the caveat here is `ListLinePlot` is effectively showing a linear interpolation regardless of the order of the input interpolation.  Its also useful to know you can `ListPlot` this way and readily see the actual solution points coming from `NDSolve`.   Stranegly this doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: @george2079 Yes, it's connect-the-dots, which is the reason for the condition, "If the sampling is dense enough." Perhaps, I should have been clearer. It can be an advantage over `Plot`, in terms of speed. BTW, `ListLinePlot[.., Mesh -> All]` will plot both the graph and the solution points. I don't remember where I learned this, but I use it a lot, most recently [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129511/4999).

Answer (score 5):

As already noted in the comments my [`styleSplitter`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87113/121) will handle this, as will [xslittlegrass's `restylePlot2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59805/121).  If you are after the simplest possible method (least code) this is the best I can think of at the moment:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] /.
  {d_, x__Line} :> {d, Riffle[{x}, {Red, Blue}, {1, -2, 2}]}
```

This could be hard-coded for only two `Line` expressions but `Riffle` is more general.

---

It occurs to me that you did not forbid modifying the InterpolatingFunction expression, therefore we could split that in two before plotting:

```
f1 = MapAt[First, f, {4, All, 1}];
f2 = MapAt[Last,  f, {4, All, 1}];

Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

Answer (score 4):

In version 9.0, you can also use

```
Plot[f[x] , {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> (i = 1; {{Red, Green}[[i++]], #} &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: i can confirm this doesn't work in 10..in fact v10 seems to not like any sort of function for `PlotStyle`

Answer (score 3):

Another way is as following:
First, lets define a InterpolationFunction with n=30 curves.

```
    n = 30; f = 
    Interpolation[Table[{x, Table[x^j, {j, 1, n}]}, {x, 2, 5, 10^-3}]]
```

This LogPlot schows different colors.

```
    pl2 = LogPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[With[{i = i}, Hold[f[x][[i]]]], {i, n}], {x, 2, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> Table[Hue[.8 j/n ], {j, 0, n - 1}]] // Timing
```

Although f has to be evaluated several times, it is even faster than the standard Plot.

```
    pl3 = LogPlot[f[x], {x, 2, 5}] // Timing
```

That means, time consumption for the solution pl2 can be neglected.

Comment: great.. this is effectively building up the list I wrote by hand in the question. Good to know how to do that!